# How to merge updates in source code instead of replacing with latest version in npm install package@latest?

Tags: npm, merge

I have uploaded a package on npm which a user can install and making required changes in the source code. Currently, when I install the latest version over pre-installed but modified package using

> npm install packageName@latest

to update it to the latest version; my modifications are overwritten. I want to get the latest version but keep my changes as well. One can say, I want to merge the latest version with my modifications. Any help to achieve this goal will be appreciated.

Comment: Three options: (1) make an PR to the Git repo of the package to apply your changes to future official release, (2) move your overwritten code out of node_modules to project folder and keep it there or (3) folk the Git repo of that package to your own Git, apply your modification there and use your repo instead of npm repo.

Comment: @blaz Is there not any way to do it using npm ?

Comment: Npm simply helps you to download and manage packages from defined sources; it does not do code merging or version control. Thus don't directly modify inside node_modules: the changes only apply inside your local machine, and you have to ask every of your colleagues to make the same changes to make their code work. It should not be that way.